# Package Assignment problem to maximize profit

Tags: linear-programming, mixed-integer-programming

**Problem description**

We have a graph $G=(V,E)$. $V$ is the set of nodes. $c_{ij}$ is the profit of traveling through edge $(i,j)$. $T=\{1,2,3,...\}$ is the set of discrete time steps.

At each time step, we have a set of packages that we need to transport to their destination. $d^t_{i,j}$ is the maximum number of packages that needs to be transported from $i$ to $j$ at time $t$. $X^t_{i}$ is the total number of available trucks available at the factory $i$ at time $t$. $B^t$ is the set of available trucks at time $t$. Each truck $n$ is associated with a capacity $r_n$.

We assume that at each time step we don't need to assign all the packages to the trucks.

**Objective**

Assign the packages to trucks such that the profit is maximized

$$ $$

I would like to model the problem mentioned above as a linear programming optimization problem. I have limited experience in LP. Following is my current formulation of the problem. I tried to run a solver. But it can't solve it, even with a simple example.

Can anyone tell me what the problem with the formulation is? I would appreciate any feedback.

$$\max  \sum_{i,j \in V} \sum_{n \in B} x^t_{ij}c^t_{ij}z^t_{in}$$
$$0\le x^t_{ij} \le d^t_{ij} \quad \forall i,j \in V \quad (1)$$
$$0\le x^t_{ij} \le \sum_{n \in B}z^t_{in}r_n \quad \forall i,j \in V \quad (2)$$
$$\sum_{n \in B}z^t_{in} \le 1 \quad \forall i \in V \quad (3)$$
$$z^t_{in} \in \{0,1\}$$

*Constraints:*

$(1)$ represents that the number of packages to be transferred is not more than the available packages.

$(2)$ ensures that the number of packages doesn't exceed the capacity of the trucks.

$(3)$ to make sure each truck is selected once

Comment: Notice that your question doesn't include a question mark. Usually this is a sign that you haven't been clear about what you're asking.

Comment: Not just usually, but concretely here as well: I don't know what the question is here :-)

Comment: Dear all, my apologies. I have edited the question. I hope it is better now

Comment: What exactly do you mean by linear programming?

Comment: I am not sure if I understood you correctly, but I meant to model this problem as a linear optimization problem

Comment: The presence of a discrete variable means you cannot solve this problem with linear programming.

Comment: How about using (M)ILP?

Comment: @MraAbs: That'll work.